# How to cancel GCD queue?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I need to know the number of task not yet started on a serial GCD queue. The reason is that I want them to 'cancel', like this:

```
if(!canceled) {
    ... do work
  }
```

Comment: GCD doen't have any built-in support for cancellation. I would suggest using NSOperation and NSOperationQueue will be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Midhun MP change was really easy:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
// .. some code
    //HERE I need cancel queue, but with GCD it is not possible
    })
```

so the solution with `NSOperationQueue`:

```
    var oq = NSOperationQueue()
    oq.addOperationWithBlock({
// .. some code
    oq.cancelAllOperations()
    })
```